# Google Maps API running requests even if user navigates to another mapless fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my app I have a screen (fragment) with a Google Map API V2
If I open this screen, and then open the navigation drawer and click and go elsewhere in the app, for the following 2-3 seconds I can see that the map keeps on executing some requests in the background.

How do I stop these from running in onPause/onDestroy of the fragment?

[image]

Here is a part of the map code:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

            cameraUpdateAction = CameraUpdateAction.CAMERA_ANIMATE;
            return false;

        }
    });

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(onCameraChangeListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [MapFragment documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/MapFragment), it states that `Any objects obtained from the GoogleMap is associated with the view. It's important to not hold on to objects (e.g. Marker) beyond the view's life. Otherwise it will cause a memory leak as the view cannot be released.`

You might try to call the [clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear()) method of GoogleMap in MapFragment's onPause()/onDestroy() method.